# Создать Angular 7 drop-down list?

Tags: angular2, angular, dropdown

мне нужно сделать что-то вроде drop-down списка, но только элементы должны выпадать по клику и не исчезать, а исчезать только по некст клику мышки. К примеру есть у меня массив картинок, по клику на название drop-down списка все картинки из списка "выпадают" на странице, и если кликнуть еще раз, они исчезают назад в список, т.е. drop-down закрылся, как это лучше всего реализовать в Angular 7, и есть ли уже примеры подобных реализаций?

Comment: эм, мне кажется если ты загуглишь то получишь кучу результатов - нет? :D

Comment: @overthesanity, кучу, но не того, я находил только дефолтный drop-down list, как элемент меню

Comment: а в чем проблема самому сделать? я в принципе не вижу никакой сложности, даже небывалый джун такое сделает ;)

Comment: @overthesanity, если ничего не найду то сделаю сам, а так думал найти готовые решения, хотя бы как пример, чтобы велосипеды не городить

Comment: сделать сам != велосипед городить, опыт показывает что кастомные решения оказываются в разы лучше и мейнтабельнее, чем решения с интернета

Comment: Как вариант посмотри как это сделано в Angular Material https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview